# Axis2 Stub Connection Pool

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis, connection-pooling

I've been trying to create a Webservice that consumes other third party client using axis2 Stub. Im not sure if its normal that my Webservice is consuming a lot of memory on our Linux server.

Im using the axis2 stub like this

```
              log.info("Initializing PGSOAPSERVER CONNECTION");
              PGSOAPStub serviceStub = new PGSOAPStub(PGSOAP_ENDPOINT);
              PGSOAPCALL pgsoapcall = new PGSOAPCALL();
              log.info("Preparing PGSOAPCALL parameters");
              pgsoapcall.setPrmFunction("LTEDPROVAPN");
              pgsoapcall.setPrmMSISDN(disableAPNInput.getMsisdn());
              pgsoapcall.setPrmIMSI(IMSI);
              pgsoapcall.setPrmSource("MPP");
              pgsoapcall.setPrmNewIMSI("");
              pgsoapcall.setPrmSvcID("");
              log.info("Sending PGSOAPCALL request");
              String PGSOAPresult  = serviceStub.pGSOAPCALL(pgsoapcall).getPGSOAPCALLResult();
              serviceStub._getServiceClient().cleanupTransport();
```

I tried googling on how to implement a connection pool using axis2 stub but I cant find a clear tutorial for that.

Im using Axis2 1.7 and Java 8

So my question is:

- Is my current implementation applicable on PRODUCTION environment?
- How to implement an Axis2 Stub connection pool?

Thanks